Python os.system running before the commands before it
I'm a newbie at Python and I'm using the QT Pyside6 lib, so I can develop a graphical user interface for login. Basically what it does is it gets the input of the user in the self.username_field and self.password_field, then it tests the internet connection and show error if its not connected, on the other side it checks the storage option, because this login is to a network storage, and its divided into storage1 and 2, I get this data from the screen because I have two radioboxes that send the right value to the storage option. And then it creates the folder and run the mount command to connect it, if the command is sucessfull, the program ends.
def button_login_clicked(self):
    user = self.username_field.text()
    password = self.password_field.text()

    try:
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        internet = ""
    except OSError:
        internet = "no internet"

    if internet != "":
        self.select_storage_label.hide()
        self.wrong_credentials_label.hide()
        self.no_internet_label.hide()
        self.no_internet_label.show()
    else:
        if self.storage_option != "":
            if self.system == "posix":
                os.system("if ! [ -e /mnt/share ] ; then mkdir /mnt/share ; chown user. /mnt/share ; fi")
                mount = os.system(f"mount -t cifs //000.00.000.0/{self.storage_option} /mnt/share/ -o uid=user,username={user},password={password},iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp 2>/dev/null")
            else:
                # Mount network share on Windows
                mount = os.system(f"net use Z: \\\\000.00.000.0\\{self.storage_option} /user:{user} {password} /persistent:Yes")
            if mount != 0:
                self.select_storage_label.hide()
                self.no_internet_label.hide()
                self.wrong_credentials_label.hide()
                self.wrong_credentials_label.show()
            else:
                with open('login.conf', 'w') as file:
                    # Write to file
                    file.write(f"{user};{self.storage_option}")
                exit()
        else:
            self.select_storage_label.hide()
            self.no_internet_label.hide()
            self.wrong_credentials_label.hide()
            self.select_storage_label.show()


My problem is that I want a way to have a message that indicates that the system is trying to connect to the network storage, but when I try to use the command self.loading_message.show() right when the function starts, but it doesnt work, it shows nothing until the mount command is unsuccesfull. I think os.system is running before the label is showed, but i dont know why this is happening.
I tried changing os.system to subprocess.callbut the problem kept happening, I tried to find thread information to run it in separate parts but it is how I said, I'm a newbie at Python, specially Qt for Python.

Why are you using a string instead of a boolean for the internet variable? You never do anything with the text.

Changes to the display aren't rendered until all the functions return to the GUI's event loop. This allows you to make multiple changes and not see all the intermediate steps. So you need to run the network check asynchronously.

Does this answer your question? Show realtime output of subprocess in a QDialog
